# HDF5 .Net wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, hdf5

I'm getting ( http://www.hdfgroup.org/projects/hdf.net/)

> The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

from the dependency walker i'm seeing that SZLIBDLL.DLL is missing i tried to download it from random place but then i got another error.

Does any one had that problem? i tried also vs2005 and vs2008

Thanks, Pini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the binaries Agilent directs you to use:

ftp://ftp.hdfgroup.org/lib-external/szip/2.1/bin/old/windows/

Are you making sure the directories are your search paths? Same directory is usually sufficient, but it may be looking someplace else. If you try these binaries and get a -different- error, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Mason,
I download from this link 

ftp://ftp.hdfgroup.org/lib-external/szip/2.1/bin/windows/

and extract to system32 but getting the same error.
if you look in the folder there isn't any SZLIBDLL.DLL there. And in the manual it says to take the decoder but all files there are encoder ... 
can you send me yours SZLIBDLL.DLL and i will try it?

thanks a lot, Pini.

Comment: Oh strange there are two different 2.1s in that directory. This is the one I was referring to:

ftp://ftp.hdfgroup.org/lib-external/szip/2.1/bin/old/windows/

I must not have realized it was the 'old', but these have szlibdll.dll files.

Comment: Yeppp - that solve my problem, i just put SZLIBDLL.DLL in my system32 and no more runtime error. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also see this message if you're trying to run the 64-bit DLL in a 32-bit environment, or vice-versa.